# How can I get a specific item from a multidimensional array (php)?

Tags: php, arraylist, multidimensional-array

How can I get the specific item from the following array. I'd like to get the close values.

What should I do in this case?

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($req_url),true);

// print_r($data);  //give the following array;

// Array ( [chart] => Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [meta] => Array ( [currency] => USD [symbol] => SEAS [exchangeName] => NYQ [instrumentType] => EQUITY [firstTradeDate] => 1366378200 [regularMarketTime] => 1588622401 [gmtoffset] => -14400 [timezone] => EDT [exchangeTimezoneName] => America/New_York [regularMarketPrice] => 14.55 [chartPreviousClose] => 14.11 [previousClose] => 14.11 [scale] => 3 [priceHint] => 2 [currentTradingPeriod] => Array ( [pre] => Array ( [timezone] => EDT [end] => 1588599000 [start] => 1588579200 [gmtoffset] => -14400 ) [regular] => Array ( [timezone] => EDT [end] => 1588622400 [start] => 1588599000 [gmtoffset] => -14400 ) [post] => Array ( [timezone] => EDT [end] => 1588636800 [start] => 1588622400 [gmtoffset] => -14400 ) ) [tradingPeriods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [timezone] => EDT [end] => 1588622400 [start] => 1588599000 [gmtoffset] => -14400 ) ) ) [dataGranularity] => 5m [range] => 1d [validRanges] => Array ( [0] => 1d [1] => 5d [2] => 1mo [3] => 3mo [4] => 6mo [5] => 1y [6] => 2y [7] => 5y [8] => 10y [9] => ytd [10] => max ) ) [timestamp] => Array ( [0] => 1588599000 [1] => 1588599300 [2] => 1588599600 [3] => 1588599900 [4] => 1588600200 [5] => 1588600500 ) [indicators] => Array ( [quote] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [open] => Array ( [0] => 13.3599996567 [1] => 13.8599996567 [2] => 13.720000267 [3] => 13.8800001144 [4] => 14.0349998474 [5] => 14.051199913 ) [close] => Array ( [0] => 13.9499998093 [1] => 13.7299995422 [2] => 13.8400001526 [3] => 14.0450000763 [4] => 14.0600004196 [5] => 14.1899995804 ) [high] => Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 13.8599996567 [2] => 13.9399995804 [3] => 14.0900001526 [4] => 14.1000003815 [5] => 14.2600002289 ) [low] => Array ( [0] => 13.1099996567 [1] => 13.5900001526 [2] => 13.720000267 [3] => 13.8699998856 [4] => 13.8509998322 [5] => 14 ) [volume] => Array ( [0] => 124733 [1] => 49489 [2] => 51657 [3] => 48362 [4] => 34055 [5] => 36566 ) ) ) ) ) ) [error] => ) );

```
 $close=  $data['chart']['result']['indicators']['close'] ;

 echo $close;
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to approach, could you please improve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Array:

```
Array ( [chart] => 
Array ( [result] => 
Array ( [0] => 
Array ( [meta] => 
Array ( [currency] => USD [symbol] => SEAS [exchangeName] => NYQ [instrumentType] => EQUITY [firstTradeDate] => 1366378200 [regularMarketTime] => 1588622401 [gmtoffset] => -14400 [timezone] => EDT [exchangeTimezoneName] => America/New_York [regularMarketPrice] => 14.55 [chartPreviousClose] => 14.11 [previousClose] => 14.11 [scale] => 3 [priceHint] => 2 [currentTradingPeriod] => 
Array ( [pre] => 
Array ( [timezone] => EDT [end] => 1588599000 [start] => 1588579200 [gmtoffset] => -14400 ) [regular] => 
Array ( [timezone] => EDT [end] => 1588622400 [start] => 1588599000 [gmtoffset] => -14400 ) [post] => 
Array ( [timezone] => EDT [end] => 1588636800 [start] => 1588622400 [gmtoffset] => -14400 ) ) [tradingPeriods] => 
Array ( [0] => 
Array ( [0] => 
Array ( [timezone] => EDT [end] => 1588622400 [start] => 1588599000 [gmtoffset] => -14400 ) ) ) [dataGranularity] => 5m [range] => 1d [validRanges] => 
Array ( [0] => 1d [1] => 5d [2] => 1mo [3] => 3mo [4] => 6mo [5] => 1y [6] => 2y [7] => 5y [8] => 10y [9] => ytd [10] => max ) ) [timestamp] => 
Array ( [0] => 1588599000 [1] => 1588599300 [2] => 1588599600 [3] => 1588599900 [4] => 1588600200 [5] => 1588600500 ) [indicators] => 
Array ( [quote] => 
Array ( [0] => 
Array ( [open] => 
Array ( [0] => 13.3599996567 [1] => 13.8599996567 [2] => 13.720000267 [3] => 13.8800001144 [4] => 14.0349998474 [5] => 14.051199913 ) [close] => 
Array ( [0] => 13.9499998093 [1] => 13.7299995422 [2] => 13.8400001526 [3] => 14.0450000763 [4] => 14.0600004196 [5] => 14.1899995804 ) [high] => 
Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 13.8599996567 [2] => 13.9399995804 [3] => 14.0900001526 [4] => 14.1000003815 [5] => 14.2600002289 ) [low] => 
Array ( [0] => 13.1099996567 [1] => 13.5900001526 [2] => 13.720000267 [3] => 13.8699998856 [4] => 13.8509998322 [5] => 14 ) [volume] => 
Array ( [0] => 124733 [1] => 49489 [2] => 51657 [3] => 48362 [4] => 34055 [5] => 36566 ) ) ) ) ) ) [error] => ) );
```

You need:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($req_url),true);
    $close = $data['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['currentTradingPeriod']['pre']['regular']['post']['tradingPeriods'][0][0]['validRanges']['timestamp']['indicators']['quote'][0]['open']['close'];
    echo $close;
?>
```

**UPDATE:** Your comment shows different array. You need:

```
<?php
    $req_url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/SEAS?&interval=5m';
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($req_url), true);
    $close = $data['chart']['result'][0]['indicators']['quote'][0]['close'];
    print_r($close);
?>
```

Comment: Cant see anything yet:
<?php
 $req_url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/SEAS?&interval=5m';
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($req_url),true);

foreach($data as $x => $x_value) {
  
  $close = $x_value['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['currentTradingPeriod']['pre']['regular']['post']['tradingPeriods'][0][0]['validRanges']['timestamp']['indicators']['quote'][0]['open']['close'];
    echo $close . "<br/>";
}
?>

Comment: Great! it does. Thanks

Comment: @javfeli Great :) Please mark this question as solved if it helped.

Comment: Marked but popup shows message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.